# How can I build software using Qt 5.5 which runs on old Linux systems (e.g. RedHat 4 or RedHat 5)?

Tags: linux, qt, deployment, qt5

I'm trying to compile an application (the [Qt Installer Framework](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Installer-Framework)) which uses Qt 5.5 such that the resulting (statically-linked) binaries work on older Linux systems such as RedHat 5 or maybe even RedHat 4.

My understanding is that in order to generate binaries which run on some specific Linux distribution I should build them on a system with a compatible (i.e. sufficiently old) glibc version, which in turn appears to depend on some Linux kernel version (for syscalls or so?). The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-getting-started.html) recommends to configure the Qt build via

```
$ configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -release -static -accessibility -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-xcb -qt-pcre -qt-freetype -no-glib -no-cups -no-sql-sqlite -no-qml-debug -no-opengl -no-egl -no-xinput -no-xinput2 -no-sm -no-icu -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtenginio -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtserialport -skip qtquick1 -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtscript -skip qtsensors -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtxmlpatterns
```

Alas, even when disabling so many Qt components, building Qt 5.5 on very old Linux systems appears to be problematic due to a dependency on some [xcb](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/) version (1.5 or 1.7 if I remember correctly) which is only available on RHEL6 or newer.

This makes me wonder: is it possible to build software using Qt 5.5 such that the resulting binaries can be deployed to older Linux distributions (RedHat 4 & 5 is still somewhat popular in the commercial word)? If so, do I maybe need to configure Qt with some specific flags or the like? For what it's worth, I don't need most of the Qt functionality. Just core, widgets and QML (for scripting) but no WebKit or SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to compile xcb on those systems, then build Qt with that xcb library and ship it with your application. If I understand this correctly:

> Since the protocol is standardized, a client using any implementation
>   of XCB may talk with any X server (the same occurs for Xlib, of
>   course).

from [this XCB tutorial](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/), an xcb client will still talk to any X server, since the underlying protocol hasn't changed. But you'll have to do some experimenting...

Comment: That's interesting, it's at least something to try. I hope I could do a static build such that I don't need to ship a separate shared object.

Comment: Accepting this - turns out I did a static libxcb build and then patched the Qt build system such that it uses `$PKG_CONFIG --libs --static xcb` to get the linker flags for libxcb (i.e. I added `--static`).